# Path handling when opening a file in emacs

Tags: emacs

Ok, this is probably simple to do, but I just can't find how.

When opening a file in emacs, I use:  `C-x C-f`.  Which then drops me down into the command buffer with the current path already filled out.

In previous setups (other companies), I could just hit `/` and it would eliminate the current path, replacing it with the root directory `/`.  Or, I could hit `~`, and it would similarly clear out the path, going to my home directory `~`.

In my current setup, I do not have that feature.  I would like to turn that on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still start by typing `/` or `~`, and any input before that will be ignored.  E.g. if the minibuffer contains `/home/foo//tmp/bar.txt`, then `/tmp/bar.txt` will be opened.

There should be visual feedback for this, showing the part that will be ignored in a dimmer colour.  Check that `file-name-shadow-mode` is `t` (it is by default), and that the `shadow` face is considerably different from the `default` face.  I found that I had activated a colour theme that didn't really distinguish the two, so I typed `M-x customize-face RET shadow` and made it darker.

I seem to remember that there is a mode that actually deletes the part of input that will be ignored, but I can't find it now...

Comment: I didn't know about shadow mode -- that's very helpful to know.  But I would prefer the mode that deletes the ignored input (I can't find it either).

Answer (score 1):

It won't provide exactly the same functionality as you describe, but [`ido`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings) can come very close to the desired behavior. As the bonus you get better navigation through the directories and files.